# how can set header mediator value with runtime value in WSO2 APIM 2.6?

Tags: http-headers, wso2, wso2-api-manager, mediator

I get a token authorization parameter from a Login API. I need to use this token in my header parameters I gave with In Flow mediator in another API.so I try use CORS configuration and get the token parameter as type header and fill it when invoking the API.

I gave this token value in mediator with static value and It worked. But this value is dynamically changed by invoking Login API so I have to give run time value.

my mediator is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="tokenMediator" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="full"/>
    <header name="caller-token" scope="transport" value="123"/>
    <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
    <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" value="http://onlinewebapi"/>
    <header expression="$header:token" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
</sequence>
```

when I invoke API I get this : "TypeError: Failed to fetch"
and it don't pass WSO2 to reach my local codes.
I changed the name of parameter from token to authorization and result don't changed.

Comment: Do you need to send access token to backend?

Comment: Actually it's a caller-token that I generate with some random methods in my Login API and use it as a input token for my another APIs. I use [Pass a Custom Authorization Token to the Backend](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Pass+a+Custom+Authorization+Token+to+the+Backend) and it work.